# Excel VBA - Writing multiple userform checkbox values to a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, concatenation, userform

I am trying to take the values passed from a userform that has 4 checkbox options and write them to a single concatenated cell.

When I select my userform like this:

[image]

I would like to save it to a single cell like this:

[image]

I tried accomplishing this with the following code (see below), but it doesn't work quite right with the commas and such if only the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th item is chosen without the first. I am convinced there is a better way but I can't figure it out or find an answer online.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  Dim colors As String

   If chkRed = True Then
      colors = "Red"
   Else
      colors = colors
   End If

   If chkBlue = True Then
      colors = colors & ", Blue"
   Else
      colors = colors
   End If

   If chkGreen = True Then
      colors = colors & ", Green"
   Else
      colors = colors
   End If

   If chkYellow = True Then
      colors = colors & ", Yellow"
   Else
      colors = colors
   End If

   With colorsSheet
      .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = colors
   End With

   Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the frame control to `frameColours` then you can loop its checkboxes & build your string;

```
Dim chk as Control
Dim colors as string, delimiter as string

for Each chk In Me.frameColours.Controls
    if typeOf chk Is msforms.CheckBox then
        if (chk.Value) then
            colors = colors & delimiter & chk.Caption
            delimiter = ","
        end if
    end if
next

With colorsSheet
    .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = colors
End With
```

Comment: Alex, that looks great. Thank you so much. I will try it out here and let you know how it goes. I haven't learned how to do it this way before and knew there must be a better way out there.

Comment: Worked great. Only change I had to make was to add a space to the delimiter to change it from "," to ", "

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

Dim lngIndex As Long, strTemp As String


For lngIndex = 1 To 16

'There are 16 check boxex, hence 1 to 16 is given

If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & lngIndex) Then
    strTemp = strTemp & Me.Controls("TextBox" & lngIndex).Value & vbLf 

'Returns you the output in a new line within the same cell.

End If

Next lngIndex

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Left$(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the initial comma from output like ", Blue, Green, Yellow", you're going to have to change the code that adds those strings to check whether `colors` is empty. Something like:

```
If chkBlue = true Then
    If colors = "" Then
        colors = "Blue"
    Else
        colors = colors & ", Blue"
    End If
End If
```

Since "Red" is the first color you add, you can assume that `colors` is empty:

```
If chkRed = True Then
      colors = "Red"
End If
```

You dont' need `Else ... colors = colors`

Comment: I like (and upvoted) @Alex K.'s solution. It uses less code, and won't require code changes if you add colors.

Comment: Tim, you are right. Alex has a great solution. I like yours as well because it fixes my code as it stands. Glad to have 2 ways of accomplishing what I set out to do. Thank you.