# Fill cell from userform (one out of several checkboxes)

Tags: excel, checkbox

I am sure someone else has asked this, but I can't find a post with an answer that fits my situation.  I am trying to fill and excel sheet from a userform.  The first cell will be filled with one of several choices that are available.  Each choice is allotted its own checkbox.  This is due to the format of the paper form that my database is based off of.  The picture shows the separate checkboxes.  How would I go about this?  And is it possible to ensure that only one checkbox is used at a time?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: is it [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343473/excel-vba-writing-multiple-userform-checkbox-values-to-a-single-cell) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard this question.  I found a simple stacked method of achieving my goal here.  I used this example I found on a forum and tried stacking more than one.  It worked, but only one can be checked at a time to create a record.

`If "X" = True Then
      Sheets("Y").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ("Z")
    End If`

X = Checkbox Name

Y = Destination Sheet

Z = Checkbox Caption (or other desired caption)

If more than one is checked, the form will spit out the following error:

"Run-Time Error '9':

Subscript out of range."